# Numpy in blender: having a lot of trouble

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, blender

I'm having a lot of difficulty getting numpy to work in blender. I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and Blender 2.77. I've already tried moving the numpy folder into blender/2.77/scripts/modules. No luck. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M7iC.jpg) is a screenshot of what I get when I try to import numpy in the python interpreter within blender. Numpy works fine outside of blender. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have that issue on another OS, also it's not just blender and numpy. It comes down to numpy using GCC to compile some parts of it (it uses fortran which prevents the use of clang) which is then linked to some libraries supplied by GCC. When numpy is imported it fails to import a compatible version of these libraries and when an older version is found it fails to load.

The reason this happens is blender first loads the older versions of GCC libraries, then when numpy is loaded the pre-loaded library is used as a matching library by name but fails to match the version needed. There has been some indication that cmake is removing rpath settings during linking that leads to this.

The solution is to get blender to load the newer versions so they match the requirements for numpy. Newer library versions include older version compatibility shims that allow programs built with older versions to work with the newer libraries, so it is usually ok to use a newer library version than the program was compiled with.

First locate the libraries installed by GCC, look for copies of libgcc_s.so libgfortran.so and libquadmath.so. They may be in a path like /usr/local/lib/gcc48 or /opt/local/lib/gcc50

Define the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the path to the newest version before starting blender.

The solution I use is a script containing -

```
#!/bin/sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gcc49/

exec /usr/local/bin/blender "$@"
```

which I run instead of running blender directly.